# Proving a couple things about $\beta(t) = \alpha(t) - s(t)\cos(\theta)u$, where $\alpha$ is a helix. Is this correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

> Let $\alpha: I \mapsto \mathbb{R^3}$ be a helix and $u$ be the constant unit vector whose angle $\theta$ with $\alpha'(t)$ is constant. Let $s(t)$ be the arclength function of $\alpha$ starting at $t = 0$. Consider the curve $\beta(t) = \alpha(t) - s(t)\cos(\theta)u$ and prove that:
>
> a) $\beta$ is contained in the plane that goes through $\alpha(0)$ and is orthogonal to $u$
>
> b) Prove that $K_\beta = \cfrac{K_\alpha}{\sin^2(\theta)}$

b) is easy, but I'm having some trouble with a). Everything I tried got hairy pretty fast. I think there might be a typo and I should consider $\beta'$ as the curve contained in the mentioned plane, 'cause I've already proven it in that case and it makes much more sense, but I'm not sure.

**Progress:** I think I got it. Assuming, WLOG, that $\alpha$ is a unit speed curve, since $\beta'(t) \cdot u =( \alpha'(t) - s'(t)\cos(\theta)u)\cdot u = \cos(\theta)-\cos(\theta) = 0$, we can integrate and find that $\beta(t) \cdot u = c$... and for anyone seeing this who wants the answer, see the discussion in the comments, because the previous update had an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation isn't quite right, as $\alpha'(t)\cdot u = s'(t)\cos\theta$. (Recall that $s'(t)$ is the speed with which the particle moves.) [You also never defined $\theta$ in your question!]

Note that $s(t)$ is the arclength starting at $t=0$, so $s(0)=0$. This shows that  $\beta(0)=\alpha(0)$. Now, can you show that $\big(\beta(t)-\alpha(0)\big)\cdot u = 0$ for all $t$?

Comment: Here I assumed the curve $\alpha$ is parameterized by arclength, so $s(t) = \int_0^t ||\alpha'(s)|| \ ds$, whence $s'(t) = 1$, so $\alpha'(t) \cdot u = \cos(\theta)$. I'll fix the question, sorry, $\theta$ is the angle between the unit vector $v$ and $\alpha'(t)$. 

I thought I already showed that $(\beta(t) - \alpha(0)) \cdot u = 0$ in my original computation, since $\beta'(t) \cdot u = 0$ , so $\beta(t) \cdot u$ is constant, and since it is $0$ at $t = 0$ it must be zero everywhere, from which follows $(\beta(t) - \alpha(0))\cdot u = 0, \forall t \in I $ 

Are there any mistakes here?

Comment: But $\beta(0)\cdot u$ isn't necessarily $0$. This would only be the case if we project onto the plane through the origin with normal vector $u$. ... Since the question wasn't written assuming an arclength parametrization, it's confusing if you just assume that without saying so. ...

Comment: I assumed $\beta(0) \cdot u = \alpha(0) \cdot u = 0$ because $\alpha(0)$ lies in the plane through $\alpha(0)$ orthogonal to $u$ (because we're talking about exactly that plane). Is this wrong? If so, how could I fix my argument? I did put at the very end of my computations the fact that I was assuming an arclength parametrization, but you're right, I should be clearer about that and put it at the start.

Comment: You're assuming things that are wrong!! Your argument only works if $\alpha(0)$ lies in the plane through the origin with normal $u$.

Comment: I see. What would be the right way to go here? Is $\beta(t) \cdot u = c$ correct, though? How can I proceed my argument (starting off from the last point where it was correct... or must I erase it all?)?

Comment: Just make the mild correction to do what I said in the second paragraph? You need to review what the equation of a plane through a given point is.

Comment: I know the equation of a plane through a given point $w$ is given by $(P - w) n = 0$, where $n$ is the normal vector to the plane and $w = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is the point the plane goes through, with $P = (x, y, z)$. About the second paragraph, that's precisely what I'm having trouble with. I can't see how to show $(\beta(t) - \alpha(0))u =  \alpha(t) \cdot u - s(t) \cos(\theta) - \alpha(0) \cdot u = 0$.

Comment: Oh I think I see now. Since by my computations $(\beta(t) - \alpha(0))' u$ is constant, and at $t = 0$ it's equal to $0$, it's zero everywhere. Is this correct?

Comment: Righto!! Sometimes you need to absorb what I write to you before you respond. :)

Comment: I do tend to speak/type faster than I think. I'll try to stop that habit, sorry :). Thanks for your patience.